# Objective-C HealthKit identify if source is from Apple iPhone or Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit

I have an app where I am trying to integrate the HealthKit and pull steps related data aggregated by day using the [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery_Class/index.html). Requirement is to pull steps data specific to only iPhone and Apple Watch devices separately (no de-duplication) which have contributed to the health app.

The **[HKSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSource_Class/index.html)** class only exposes the following properties:

- **name** - Cannot be used as the user can change this to anything from just 'XXXX iPhone'
- **bundleIdentifier** - Provides us the UUID for the device (unique per device, so different for every iPhone/Watch), and it looks like com.apple.health.UUID, here's what the Apple documentation says : "*For apps, this property holds the app’s bundle identifier. For supported Bluetooth LE devices, this property holds a UUID for the device.*"

I am able to pull all sources (using a HKSourceQuery) which have the bundleIdentifier prefix of 'com.apple.health', but am unable to deduce which is an Apple iPhone versus which is an Apple iWatch.

Has anybody faced a similar situation before, and is there any other way to identify which source is an iPhone or Apple Watch?

Any help would be great!.Thanks!

Comment: In the same situation. Something like `parentDevice` static method to return the iPhone, would be helpful here from Apple.

Comment: Hi Wilmar, please see my answer below. I found a workaround for now for this. Please accept if the answer suffices your need. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Not the best solution but, I have figured out a way to distinguish between the watch and the phone using the following process:

I noticed that all step data coming from the iPhone/Watch have the following bundleIdentifier format:

**com.apple.health.DeviceUUID**

Note that manually entered data into the Health app has a bundle identifier of com.apple.Health (with a capital 'H').

So, first thing, get the device name for the phone using:

```
NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

Next, fetch all the sources for which there is a prefix match of 'com.apple.health' in the bundleIdentifier. This should give you the iPhone and the Apple watch as the valid sources and ignore the manual entries and all other apps.

Next, check if the name of the device is the same in the source, then its your iPhone, the other source should be your Apple Watch.

Here's a sample source query for fetching the sources :

```
- (void)fetchSources 
{
    NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSMutableArray *dataSources = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    HKQuantityType *stepsCount = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
    HKSourceQuery *sourceQuery = [[HKSourceQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:stepsCount
                                                           samplePredicate:nil
                                                         completionHandler:^(HKSourceQuery *query, NSSet *sources, NSError *error)
                                                         {
                                                             for (HKSource *source in sources)
                                                             {
                                                                  if ([source.bundleIdentifier hasPrefix:sourceIdentifier])
                                                                 {

                                                                     if ([source.name isEqualToString:deviceName])
                                                                        // Iphone
                                                                     else
                                                                       // Apple Watch
                                                                     [dataSources addObject:source];
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                         }];
    [self.healthStore executeQuery:sourceQuery];
}
```

You can now create a predicate with each source for your data pull using the NSPredicate class:

```
NSPredicate *sourcesPredicate = [HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSource:source];
```

Note that my first thought was to match the UUID, but when I generate a UUID using the NSUUID class, it does not match with the one present in the bundle identifier in the pulled sources.

Also, you can change the name of the phone to whatever you want, it will automatically update in the Health app as well.

As I said, not the best solution but works for me, and it's the only way I could find to do this. Please let me know if you were able to find a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer can get a device. How about list devices like Sources tab item in Health app? Do you have any solutions?

Comment: @SiNguyen Unfortunately, I could not figure this out at that time. But I know that there was a plan to come out with more device specific information in iOS 9 if I remember correctly. Did you have a look at the official docs to see if anything new has bed been added? Cheers.

Comment: @SiNguyen what about this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobject/1615622-device?changes=latest_minor

Comment: I found it but i don't know what the query is :(

Comment: A different way to use sources is to add .separateBySource HKStatisticsOptions, and then read the sumQuantity for that particular source. See https://www.devfright.com/how-to-use-the-hkstatisticscollectionquery/ for more details.